# How to copy the /bin files along with dependencies using commands?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, command, initrd

The /bin folder of Ubuntu 14.04 has files with dependencies. I want to copy the symbolic links along with the files, into a separate directory. Is there an inbuilt command for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "dependencies"? It _could_ mean "the libraries that each command is using".

Comment: Yes, I meant libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Use cp -P (capital P) to move any symbolic link and copy the symbolic link instead.

This can be combined with other options such as -R to copy a directory hierarchy — cp -RL traverses all symbolic links to directories, cp -RP copies all symbolic links as such. cp -R might do one or the other depending on the unix variants; GNU cp (as found on CentOS) defaults to -P.

Even with -P, you can copy the target of a symbolic link to a directory on the command line by adding a / at the end: cp -RP foo/ bar copies the directory tree that foo points to.

GNU cp has a convenient -a option that combines -R, -P, -p and a little more. It makes an exact copy of the source (as far as possible), preserving the directory hierarchy, symbolic links, permissions, modification times and other metadata.
shareeditflag

Comment: Using these commands, cp -RP and cp -a, breaks the links and the files cannot be accessed after that.